# add delimiters to a phone number

Tags: php, explode

I need to turn this phone number:

```
5555555555
```

into this string with delimiters:

```
"555.555.5555"
```

Here's my code:

```
$phone = 5555555555;
$phoneArray = explode(2, $phone);
print_r($phoneArray);
```

and it returns this:

```
Array ( [0] => 555 [1] => [2] => 55555 )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first argument to [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is a delimiter; what is the purpose of the `2`?

Comment: im new to PHP explode and i thought it meant explode on not 0, or 1 but on 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this, and RegEx not required, but here's a nice and easy one w/ RegEx:

```
$phone = '5555555555';
echo preg_replace('/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/', "$1.$2.$3", $phone);
```

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

You need something more like this:

```
$number = '123456789';
$segments = array();

$segments[] = substr($number, 0, 3);
$segments[] = substr($number, 3, 3);
$segments[] = substr($number, 6, 4);

$number = implode('.', $segments); // Comes out to 123.456.7890
```

Note that you'll want to do some format checking first.  You'll need to verify
that they actually entered a 10-digit number with no dividing symbols.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to use explode since you don't have a known delimiter within the string to cause the split.  You could use str_split($phone,3) which would give you 3 array elements of 3, and a 4th of 1.  Keep the first two and merge the final two together into your 3rd array elemnent:

```
$phone = 5555555555;
$phoneArray = str_split($phone,3);
$phoneArray[2] .= phoneArray[3];

print_r($phoneArray);
```

Hope that helps.